# Display module in all pages of site except admin pages DNN7

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-settings

I am using DNN7.

I have added a HTML module on my DNN7 site which **needs to displayed on all the pages except admin pages**.So i configured in settings of the module which said display module on all pages.But the problem i am facing is when i check this option to display on all pages the module is getting displayed on admin pages too which i don't require.****Is their any option to disable the module on admin pages and show only site pages.****Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such an option. You just have to remove it manually from the admin pages you mostly use

Comment: That is correct. ONE other potential option (highly uncommon) would be to have a Skin for your Admin pages, that has the Pane where these "display on all pages" modules displayed, hidden.